# Trying to set up a web server, but my IP address looks very strange

Tags: server, ip, router, https

I want to use a raspberry pi as a web server. For this I need my public IP address. When I ask google what is my ip, I get:

```
3b01:302:kr18:9847:b40c:mn93:4567:3d91
```

NOTE: only the shape of my actual IP address is above, I have changed every digit and letter, so there is no need to worry about that.
Does anyone know what this is? I also cannot access my pi (even though I did port forwarding on my router).

Also here is the ipv6tables readout:

```
pi@pi-desktop:~$ sudo ip6tables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source                  destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

EDIT: If I use whatismyip.com I can also see that the ip information section shows the server of my ISP, in a city far away from where I live.

I also looked here: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/   and it seems that all my ports are closed and there is no option in the router's menu to open them. This site also gives me a normal ipv4 address.

Comment: How exactly did you ask google for your IP address? Try something like http://ifconfig.me/ or http://whatismyip.com/.

Comment: You just type into the google search bar "what is my ip". ifconfig.me does not seem to work, whatismyip.com gives the exact 31 character sequence that google gives.

Comment: OK, I see why: "leading zeroes" can be omitted, so "...:0302:..." can show as "...:302:..." thus making the address appear shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) IP address. Ubuntu supports IPv6 by default so that should be no problem.

Comment: But why can't I connect from outside my LAN? I did log into my router and forwarded to my raspi's local ip, so it should normally work. It just says network unreachable.

Comment: It *looks* like an IPv6 address but it's not: `3b01:302:kr18:9847:b40c:mn93:4567:3d91` it has letters that are invalid for hexadecimal digits and the length (not counting the colons) is 31 digits, not 32 as an IPv6 address should have.

Comment: @roadmr:  In the question Qubix wrote he/she "changed every digit and letter". Most likely he accidentally removed one, too.

Comment: I missed that :) sorry.

Comment: Actually, the correct ip address I get if I just type in google "what is my ip" also has 31 digits (not counting the colons). How can this be? Also, if I do this from the raspi, google gives me a different ipv6 address as the one I get from my laptop, even though they are both connected to the same router.